# Jinja2: "DeprecationWarning: The 'autoescape' extension is deprecated and will be removed in Jinja 3.1."

Tags: python, flask, jinja2

With the latest `jinja2` bump version to `3.0.0`, I started running into this error in my `Flask` application:

```
.../anaconda3/envs/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/jinja2/environment.py:119: DeprecationWarning: The 'autoescape' extension is deprecated and will be removed in Jinja 3.1. This is built in now.
  result[extension.identifier] = extension(environment)
.../anaconda3/envs/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/jinja2/environment.py:119: DeprecationWarning: The 'with' extension is deprecated and will be removed in Jinja 3.1. This is built in now.
  result[extension.identifier] = extension(environment)
```

For the record, my current `Flask` version is `1.1.2`.

Answer (score 2):

Simply upgrade your `Flask` application to the latest version - `2.0.0`:

```
pip install Flask --ignore-installed
```

That should solve the issue.

However, if upgrading the version is not an option, as an alternative on can just clear the default `jinja2` extensions that are initially loaded by `Flask` by doing:

```py
app = Flask(__name__)
app.jinja_options = {}
...
```

Comment: Thanks. Second option also works for `Quart`.